# Creating shuffled numbers in R

Tags: r, random, sample, sampling

As a result of seeing [**THIS EXAMPLE**](https://www.randomizer.org/tutorial/lesson2.html#2), I was wondering how I could create **one set** of 15 shuffled orderings of 1 through 4 in `R`?

On [**THIS Website**](https://www.randomizer.org/), you can get  1 Set of 15 shuffled Numbers
Ranging: From 1 to 4

As an example, on my run I got:

Set #1: 
3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 1

Is there a way I can replicate the above in `R`?

Comment: I don't understand what the desired result you want is exactly. Do you just want the numbers 1-4 to each appear 10 times in random order? How about `sample(rep(1:4, 10))`? Or did you just want to convert the result from `replicate` into a simple vector: `as.vector(replicate(40, sample(1:4)))`?

Comment: @MrFlick, that should do it Thanks!

Comment: @MrFlick, `sample(rep(1:4, 10))` is what I'm looking for but what if instead of `40` we had `15`?

Comment: That's not a multiple of 4 so I'm not sure how you could have random ordering of 1-4 if you only choose 15 values. It would depend on exactly what process you are trying to model.

Comment: I'm not going to try to guess what that program might be doing. It's not obvious to me. It would be best if you described in words in this question exactly what you want to happen.

Comment: There's only 1 for 4 in your new example. That doesn't seem like it's shuffling other wise I would expect at least 3 in 15. They must just be doing `sample(1:4, 15, replace=TRUE)` and by chance, you might not choose every group. If you "unshuffle" that you get `c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4)` which makes me think that's not a shuffle of anything. more like a random draw from a uniform discrete distribution.

Comment: I don't think that's true of their site. I choose the range 1-4 and choose to pick 4 elements and I got `1,1,4,4`. There was no 2 or 3. So you're not guaranteed to get all the numbers. I have no idea what criteria they are using. And unless you can tell us, it's not really possible to help you.

Comment: @MrFlick, wow! thank you so much for letting me know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly your question, at first it comes to mind a solution like the following one: very basic, but it does its job.

```
size <- 40
vec <- sample(1:4, size = size, replace = TRUE)
while(length(unique(vec)) < 4){
    vec <- sample(1:4, size = size, replace = TRUE)
}
vec
```

The `while` cycle will not go on for long as it's very unlikely that a digit does not appear in the random vector `vec` if you sample 40 times.

Of course you can change the `size` of your vector, the code will still work, except you want `vec` to be < 4; in that case, the loop will go on indefinitely.

Comment: Yes, I've tried with a small vector size and a 'print' function inside the while loop. The loop stopped when 'vec' contained at least one of all digits between 1 and 4. As an example, I set size=6 and the while loop took three iterations to spit out a vector like one that you wanted.